# DNS reduce A record lookup time before try to other A record

Tags: dns, failover

I am working on Backup server (failover) for my websites.

example.com is my domain, Host on IP `1.1.1.1`

Copy of example.com, Host on IP `2.2.2.2`

> I want to use IP2 as backup only when IP 1 is down,

so i set both IPS in my DNS A record.

**As per rule of DNS:** if i set 2 IPs in A record, then it will work like round robin.

```
First visitor redirect on IP 1.1.1.1
Second Visitor redirect on IP 2.2.2.2
```

But i set "A record" Priority in DNS, So its always redirect all users to IP `1.1.1.1`, and no users redirect on IP2 hosting.

Now, When IP 1.1.1.1 is down, then its browser or DNS nature, it will try again to other A record if IP2 available. `(Its working perfect, and i want this thing)`

> Problem is that,

DNS keep trying to IP 1 for 30-60 seconds, after its fail, then DNS try on IP 2.

I want to reduce that DNS lookup time to 5 Seconds. I have Centos VPS with WHM.

Answer (score 0):

Round-robin DNS does not work like you appear to think it works.

Most DNS nameservers will indeed rotate a list of multiple A RRs for a given name with each response, but remember the requestor will be an intermediate recursive resolver, often shared by many end clients, and those intermediate resolvers will cache each record for a minimum of 300 seconds or the maximum of the TTL given in the record.  The intermediate resolver may or may not rotate the A RRs in the responses it sends to its individual clients.  However ultimately the choice of address to try first between multiple A RRs for the same name is up to the client and some clients work differently.

The timeout for trying another address when multiple A RRs are given is mandated by the client through it's TCP connection attempt, not by anything supplied in a DNS response.